# How to write a program to identify escape sequences in C and print their values?

Tags: c

We know some escape sequence '\n' - new line but say we don't know if \a, \b, \c .... \z is an escape sequence. How to write a program that allows us to test every character from a to z and/or A to Z in a printf statement or other way to identify an escape sequence and if it is, then print it's value e.g. ouput may look like this:

'\b' is a special character and value of '\b' = 8

This program may look silly but I am not able to find a solution for it...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it defeats the purpose of writing a program, you could just google for all those escape sequences...

Comment: Is this HW? Why do you need to print them all out? They're listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Do you need this program to be in any particular language? If not, you can just write a shell script that repeatedly compiles and runs a C program that prints \x for each character x and see what it outputs.

Comment: Also check out these guys: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe.aspx They'll get you head scratch' if you don't know what's going on!

Comment: I don't know if it is worth spending time on this program. But, I am revising K&R and exercise 1.2 asks us to try this out. So I thought wouldn't it be a good idea to write a program for that?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Cultural difference - Individualism versus collectivism. If interested you may see http://www.ted.com/talks/devdutt_pattanaik.html

Comment: REvising K&R?  Have you talked to Brian Kernighan about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Carl Norum pointed out, these are interpreted by the compiler.  You can take an approach similar to autoconf (the program which generates `configure` scripts):

```
#!/bin/bash

for LETTER in {a..z}
do
    cat > letter.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("\\\\$LETTER has ASCII value %u\n", "\\$LETTER"[0]); }
EOF
    cc -Werror -o letter letter.c > /dev/null 2>&1 && ./letter
done
```

Output:

```
\a has ASCII value 7
\b has ASCII value 8
\e has ASCII value 27
\f has ASCII value 12
\n has ASCII value 10
\r has ASCII value 13
\t has ASCII value 9
\v has ASCII value 11
```

Notes:  The reason for a string constant rather than a character constant is simply shell quoting.  This relies on `gcc`'s `-Werror` but you could solve that problem in other ways.

Answer (score 4):

Read 5.2.2p2 in Standard C99 document.

Alphabetic escape sequences are:

```
\a \b \f \n \r \t \v
```

Comment: +1.  Now that I re-read the OP's question, I think you might be more on track with answering the actual question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confused about what's happening.  The *compiler* is interpreting those escape sequences, not any runtime behaviour.  Your program *can't* do what you're asking since  the `\n` or `\b` or whatever you want doesn't *exist* in that format in your program at runtime.  Rather, the string contains the actual ASCII value in place of the escape sequence you had to use in your source code since can't type a literal bell character, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This really does sound like a homework assignment, so I'll give you some strong hints:

1. look at the isprint() function to tell what's printable
2. look at any handy character chart to see how the various special characters are represented numerically.
3. To print the value, you simply need a decimal (`d`) format in printf.

Comment: A newline or a tab (for example) is a printable character and also a `printf` escape sequence.

Comment: ... and I could have written out all the code too, @CarlNorum.